# Can pyomo handle segmentation functions (defined by numpy) when defining objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, objective-function

I want to implement the following objective function in pyomo:

```
def alpha_beta(x):
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
    return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(Lmin <= x, x < Lnom),
                            np.logical_and(Lnom <= x, x <= Lmax)],
                        [lambda x: a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226,
                         lambda x: b * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226, 0])

def obj_rule(model):
    return (sum(0.00873*Dindf[i]*(w1*alpha_beta(model.x[i])+w2*alpha_beta(model.y[i]))+\
       k*(w1*abs(model.x[i+1]-model.x[i])+w2*abs(model.y[i+1]-model.y[i])) for i in model.B))+\
    k*(w1*abs(model.x[0]-L10)+w2*abs(model.y[0]-L20))+Rfc1*w1+Rfc2*w2
```

The obj_rule is my objective function in pyomo, the function alpha_beta is an external function called by obj_rule.
I got an error (part of error message):

```
/tmp/ipykernel_4287/3372018693.py in alpha_beta(x)
     40     b = 0.0078887
     41     Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
---> 42     return np.piecewise(x, [np.logical_and(Lmin <= x, x < Lnom),
     43                             np.logical_and(Lnom <= x, x <= Lmax)],
     44                         [lambda x: a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226,

pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericValue.__array_ufunc__()

pyomo/core/expr/numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericNDArray.__array_ufunc__()

pyomo/core/expr/logical_expr.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.logical_expr.InequalityExpression.__bool__()

PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant expression to bool. This error is usually caused by using an expression in a boolean context such as an if statement. For example, 
    m.x = Var()
    if m.x <= 0:
        ...
would cause this exception.
```

How to fix this and implement the objective function in the right way? Thanks!

Comment: Have you try to use [Piecewise Linear Expressions](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html#piecewise-linear-expressions) in pyomo modeling?. This can be what you need

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try the linear expressions.